# CLI design and implementation?

Tags: command-line-interface, system-design

I am developing a time management tool for my personal use. I prefer using keyboard over mouse, and on the interface have a general purpose text box which will act like a command line. I have just started thinking about what commands I need, what to use for the command names, how to pass in switches and parameters, and so forth.

I wonder if some of you have come across a good read along these lines; something that describes the choices you have for designing a cli, and how those affect the complexity of the interpreter, and extendability of the commands. It makes no difference if the descriptions are language-specific or in general terms. However, my implementation will be with javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: The Linux CLI is already completely documented via man pages.  Why not  follow the pattern of complex systems like SVN?  The Linux man pages seem to be a great description of a CLI.  What else would you like to know?

Comment: Thank you. Actually I am looking for text that describes the choices in a structured way, and explaining what impact taking different routes will have on complexity, and extendability of the interpreter. Perhaps, this is to some extent, `fear-of-unknown`. I don't want to make mistakes and waste some time only to find out latter that for specific reasons my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read this:

[http://www.amazon.com/Software-Tools-Brian-W-Kernighan/dp/020103669X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020103669X)

It explains some of the "philosophy" behind the Unix CLI.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-clutil/

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_01c

Comment: I couldn't hope for better articles. The last two are exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much.